# How do I get the target namespace and its prefix using DOM in Java?

Tags: java, xml, dom, element

Suppose I have an XML document like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema 
     targetNamespace="http://www.sample.com" 
     xmlns:sa="http://www.sample.com" 
     xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"> 
    <xs:element name="name" type="sa:NameType"/>   
    <xs:simpleType name="NameType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:maxLength value="100"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

Suppose that I have the DOM document for this schema, perhaps by doing something like this:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
documentBuilderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = = documentBuilder.parse(uriToSchema.toString());
```

How do I get the target namespace (http://www.sample.com) and its associated prefix (sa)?

I thought I could do this:

```
String namespace = ((Element) document.getDocumentElement()).getNamespaceURI());
String prefix = ((Element) document.getDocumentElement()).getPrefix());
```

But that gets the XML Schema namespace (http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema) and its associated prefix (xs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Yogi's answer pointed me in the right direction.  Here's the solution:

```
NamedNodeMap map = ((Element) document.getDocumentElement()).getAttributes();
String namespace = map.getNamedItem("targetNamespace").getNodeValue();
String prefix = "";
for (int i = 0; i < map.getLength(); i++)
{
   Attr attr = (Attr) map.item(i);
   if (attr.getValue().equals(namespace) && !attr.getName().equals("targetNamespace"))
   {
      prefix = attr.getName().split(":")[1];
      break;
   }
}
System.out.println("ns: " + namespace);
System.out.println("pr: " + prefix);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need iterate all attribute of document element like:

```
Path path = Paths.get(Typedetection.class.getClassLoader()
                 .getResource("data.xml").toURI());   

        DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        documentBuilderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = documentBuilder.parse(path.toFile());

        Element documentElement = (Element) document.getDocumentElement();
        String namespace = documentElement.getNamespaceURI();
        String prefix = documentElement.getPrefix();
        System.out.println("Namespace:"+namespace);
        System.out.println("Prefix:"+prefix);

        NamedNodeMap map = documentElement.getAttributes();
        for (int iattr=0; iattr<map.getLength(); iattr++) {
           Attr attr = (Attr)map.item(iattr);
           if (attr.getNamespaceURI() != null) {
              System.out.println("Attr " + attr.getName() + " -  " + attr.getNamespaceURI());
           }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Tested this code, and unfortunately it doesn't work.  The namespace for every attribute is "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/".

Comment: You can fix it by changing `attr.getNamespaceURI()` to `attr.getValue()`, but this still won't tell me which namespace is the targetNamespace.